# Home voltage stabilizer circuit

Tags: transformer, surge-protection

I am designing a 12000W voltage stabilizer transformer. I saw in another design that they use on the AC neutral a 10W resistor linking on the branch on relay contacts so that the neutral is taken from the relay. After some reading I realized that they might use it for transformer surge protection. Any help about this. And if there is any one know this circuit can you provide me with it so I can use it in my design.

Comment: 12kW is a power level where I would recommend taking your questions to a licensed electrician, rather than random people on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Since an interruption of an inductive current may result in a large voltage transient, there needs to be some mechanism to prevent this.  Inductive winding voltage LdI/dt may be snubbed or use oil filled contractors to absorb the surge with the e=4 transformer oil dielectric or some other method such as MOV’s or vacuum contactors with RC snubbers or ?. Series power R in Neutral? Show your schematic